# Editing Existing JSON in Python

Tags: python, simplejson

I'm pulling in some JSON from a server in the given format:

```
{"images": [{"rating": 5.0, "thumburl": "http://something.jpg", "description": "dfgd", "submitdate": "2011-01-29T07:54:02", "submituser": "J", "imagekey": "a"}, ...]}
```

I have to add a new element "viewurl" to each element using the "imagekey." For example, the result would be

```
{"images": [{"rating": 5.0, "thumburl": "http://something.jpg", "description": "dfgd", "submitdate": "2011-01-29T07:54:02", "submituser": "J", "imagekey": "a", "viewurl": "/view?imagekey=a"}, ...]}
```

There's probably an easy way to do this, but I'm having trouble finding much on simplejson other than dumps and load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
data = simplejson.loads(yourString)
for image in data['images']:
    image['viewurl'] = '/view?imagekey=%s' %(image['imagekey'])
```

You could also use an **object_hook**.  This works for your example, but you may want to tweak it a bit depending on your actual data:

```
>>> def addImageKey(dataPart):
...     if dataPart.has_key('imagekey'):
...         dataPart['viewurl'] = '/view?imagekey=%s' %dataPart['imagekey']
...     return dataPart
... 
>>> decoded_with_viewurl = json.loads(myString, object_hook = addImageKey)
```

The reason I mention the possibility of a need to tweak it is because in it's current form, the `addImageKey` object_hook will add the viewurl key/value to any object within your JSON structure that contains an `imagekey` key already.  So, you may have to use something more specific to the items in `images` if need be.

Oh, and if you want to encode it back to a JSON string, you could just change the last line to

```
>>> reencoded_with_viewurl = json.dumps(json.loads(myString, object_hook = addImageKey))
```

Depending on the amount of data you are decoding/encoding, I would suggest the possibility of using cjson to re-encode the data.  It is lightning fast in comparison to simplejson/json.  Unfortunately it does not have support for things like object_hook.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple. Is there per chance somewhere where I can find more info on simplejson?

Comment: The docs page is pretty much it... http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.1.1/docs/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest way would be to get it into python, manipulate it, and then dump it back into JSON:

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> data = simplejson.loads('''{"images": [{"rating": 5.0, "thumburl": "http://something.jpg", "description": "dfgd", "submitdate": "2011-01-29T07:54:02", "submituser": "J", "imagekey": "a"}]}''')
>>> for image in data['images']:
    key = image['imagekey']
    image["viewurl"] = "/view?imagekey=%s" % key


>>> outdata = simplejson.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is to use simplejson to de-serialze to native python, modify the native python, and serialize it back to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two options. Either use regular expressions on the string or parse the JSON into Python objects, then create a new attribute with the `imageurl` value and then generate another JSON string.